# Avoiding hardcoding of Property File path specification

Tags: java, unix

I'm having a small problem decoupling the path specification for properties files that my JAVA program uses , from the implementation itself.
The program may be deployed at multiple locations with different directory structures and I don't want the path specification to be hard coded into the Program code.

Here is the situation as it exists now.

I have one folder server/
Inside which there are 2 packages core/ & support/ (both of which have many subpackages underneath)

What I had done earlier was that , wherever the path for a properties file needed to be specified , I just gave a relative path i.e. properties/
In this scenario, the properties file needs to be wherever you're launching the program from. This worked during testing , when i was manually starting the program up using 
"java ". and i would put the properties folder wherever I was starting the program from.
But in a real scenario, this program will be autostarted by a script (ksh) which is executed at scheduled intervals by a job.

In this case , giving the relative path doesn't work. I tried putting the properties files in the folder where the scripts are located , but that doesn't work either.

Right now , I am having to manually specify the path for each environment recompile the code and deploy a separate copy for each environment. 
Is there any way to remove this coupling and just have one location for the properties file regardless of where it needs to be deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a System.Properties entry to specify the path, then on command line add it via

```
java -DmyProp=somepath -cp yourclasspath YourClass
```

In your app, you can retrieve it with `System.getProperty("myProp")`, just be sure to add proper testing and handle the Property Not Found scenario.

Another practice is to leave props in a jar and then load 'em with the LoadResource, in this way you just need to deploy different config jars in each deployment, but I think that the System.setProperty way is the fastest.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that helped me remove a final bottleneck in my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally some clients may not prefer to use -D= while starting your application. In fact you should also provide a .sh/.bat script file along with your jar file so that client can just double click on the script to run your application.

In this script you can have variable declared which you can ask the client to be configure accordingly. Client can just open the script file in text editor and type in the path of the configuration file.

Other way to use this script file would be to do following :
1) Check if YOUR_APP_NAME_CONFIG variable is set in system environment. If yes then go to step 3 or got to step 2
2) Ask the user on command line for the location of configuration file. Check if the location is correct. If correct then set the environment variable YOUR_APP_NAME_CONFIG with value of location of configuration file. 
3)Start your application

Having a script file for your application gives you lots of liberty to do many stuff around automating the environment configuration for your application.
In your application get the config file path by System.getProperty("YOUR_APP_NAME_CONFIG").

This all may look like lot of pain but think from client perspective. Its cake walk for client that he just double click a script to start your application and for the first launch of application the script asks for some inputs if needed and then your application is good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was pass another classpath parameter with the jar invocation..

`java -cp classpath1;folder-where-propertiesfile-located Application.jar`

and in the application use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream("properties-file");`

This will automatically fetch the properties file form the appropriate classpath folder..

With this setup, I could change the properties file inside the folder and use the same jar file without re-archiving the jar..